# Log4J2: How to log the exact same output to both file and console?

Tags: log4j2

The following lines are from the start of my log4j2 properties file:

```
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LOG_ROOT
rootLogger.appenderRef.startup.ref = START_UP_LOG
rootLogger.appenderRef.handler.ref = HANDLER_LOG

appender.LOG_ROOT.type = RollingFile
appender.LOG_ROOT.name = LOG_ROOT
appender.LOG_ROOT.fileName = logs/${hostName}_app.log
appender.LOG_ROOT.filePattern = logs/${hostName}_am.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.gz
appender.LOG_ROOT.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.LOG_ROOT.layout.charset = UTF-8
appender.LOG_ROOT.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p - (%F:%L) %m%n
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.type = Policies
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.LOG_ROOT.policies.size.size=5120MB
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.basePath = logs
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.ifFileName.type = IfFileName
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.ifFileName.glob = *am.log.*
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.ifAccumulatedFileCount.type = IfAccumulatedFileCount
appender.LOG_ROOT.strategy.delete.ifAccumulatedFileCount.exceeds = 180
```

In the properties file, I also have other loggers that uses the `LOG_ROOT` appender. For instance,

```
logger.ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL.name = org.hibernate.SQL
logger.ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL.level = INFO
logger.ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL.additivity = false
logger.ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LOG_ROOT
```

In addition to the existing log file, I want to display the exact same `LOG_ROOT` contents to the console as well. Is there any way I can "clone" the log output to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you use the same layout, you'll get the same output:

```
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = CONSOLE
appender.CONSOLE.type = Console
appender.CONSOLE.name = CONSOLE
appender.CONSOLE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.CONSOLE.layout.charset = UTF-8
appender.CONSOLE.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p - (%F:%L) %m%n
```

If you wish to ensure that the patterns are the same in all appenders, define a user property:

```
property.PATTERN = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p - (%F:%L) %m%n
```

and use `${PATTERN}` wherever it is required.

**Edit**: Loggers by default also log to their parent's appenders (`additivity="true"`). If you disable additivity you'll have to add a reference to the `CONSOLE` appender to each logger that directly uses `LOG_ROOT`.

In your case it is probably easier to leave additivity at its default `true` value, keep just the `LOG_ROOT` and `CONSOLE` appenders on the root logger and move the `START_UP_LOG` and `HANDLER_LOG` appender to more specific logger.

Comment: In the properties file I have other loggers that also make use of LOG_ROOT. Does this mean that I have to add this for all those other loggers?

Comment: I edited my question by providing an example of the other loggers.

Comment: If you disable additivity on other loggers, then yes: you'll have to add a reference to `CONSOLE` to the loggers that have a reference to `LOG_ROOT`. I edited the answer accordingly.